# Can a file be created from an inode?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

There is an apache process which logs to an access and error log. The two log files have been deleted, but the apache process has not been restarted or reloaded so it still has open filehandles for those log files.

I can access the file content by reading the file handle from the `/proc` directory:

```
$ sudo lsof +p 30304
...
rotatelog 30304 root    4w   REG  251,0 22480405     265346 /var/log/httpd/error_log-2014-09-11 (deleted)
```

If I then inspect the filehandles for that process I can see the file:

```
$ ls -l /proc/30304/fd
...
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 2014-09-11 10:18 4 -> /var/log/httpd/error_log-2014-09-11 (deleted)
```

I can also see the inode for that file:

```
$ ls -i /proc/30304/fd/4
1936760177 /proc/30304/fd/4
```

I can copy this file to get the current content, but any future log messages will not appear in the copied file. Is there a way to create a file that has that inode number?

This is like using `ln` to create a hard link to a file, but without having an existing file to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *do* have an existing file to reference – the one in `/proc/30304/fd`. It's just a bit tricky to use it, as regular link() refuses to accept it. You will need to use [linkat()](https://lwn.net/Articles/562488/).

Write a small C program. Put this in `foo.c`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *src, *dstdir, *dstname;
    int dirfd, r;

    if (argc < 4)
        errx(2, "not enough parameters");

    src = argv[1]; dstdir = argv[2]; dstname = argv[3];

    dirfd = open(dstdir, O_DIRECTORY);
    if (dirfd < 0)
        err(1, "open(%s) failed", dstdir);

    r = linkat(AT_FDCWD, src, dirfd, dstname, AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW);
    if (r < 0)
        err(1, "linkat(%s, %s/%s) failed", src, dstdir, dstname);

    return 0;
}
```

Run it as:

```
make foo
./foo '/proc/30304/fd/4' '/var/log' 'recovered.log'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am having a problem with the make command: `link.c:13: error: ‘O_DIRECTORY’ undeclared (first use in this function)`. Is there a missing import or do I need to satisfy some dependency on the system?

Comment: @MatthewFranglen: Ah, try including `<unistd.h>` or `<sys/stat.h>` or `<sys/types.h>` (I've no idea which, possibly all three, although it *should* have been in `<fcntl.h>` according to docs).

Comment: Might be an OS issue. When I compile the program on a different system the O_DIRECTORY flag is available.

Comment: Well, the flag is available as of Linux 2.1.126, so it should work everywhere; perhaps it just was in a different header file previously. (You could try replacing it with the direct value `0200000`.)

Comment: Your program does work on the system where I am able to compile it, so I am accepting the answer. I will play with this further. Thank you very much!